# AWS API Gateway Mapping Template - Get Object Within JSON String

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am using an AWS integration and am getting a response like the following:

```
{
   "key1": "Val1",
   "info": {\"KeyA\":\"Stuff\",\"MoreInfo\":{\"Age\":5,\"Score\":123}}
}
```

I have been trying for quite some while now to take info and return the subobject MoreInfo. The closest I get is some invalid JSON using this approach:

```
#set($inputJSON = $input.path('$'))
#set($outputString = $inputJSON.info)
#set($outputJSON = $util.parseJson($outputString))
$outputJSON.MoreInfo
```

Gives something like this.

```
{Age=5,Score=123}
```